# Como enviar datos mediante 2 botones sin refrescar pagina HTML

Tags: html

tengo un problema, estoy encendiendo un led con un Chip Wifi (Esp8266), todo me va bien tengo mis 2 botones uno que enciende y el otro que apaga mi bombilla, el problema que tengo es que al pulsar los botones se me recarga la pagina, necesito que me envíe mediante la url algo como esto:

/LED=ON  --> para encender la bombilla | | 
/LED=OFF --> para apagarla

pero sin recargar la pagina, he leído y se utiliza jquery o ajax pero no se como implementarlo en mi código, les dejare una parte del código que estoy utilizando para enviar los datos, estoy utilizando bootstrap como framework.

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<title> Control de luces </title>

<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<header> <nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation"> <div class="container"> <div class="navbar-header"> <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navegacion-fm"> <span class="sr-only">Desplegar / Ocultar Menu</span> <span class="icon-bar"></span> <span class="icon-bar"></span> <span class="icon-bar"></span> </button> <a href="" class="navbar-brand"><b>Controles</b></a> </div> <!-- Inicia Menu --> <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navegacion-fm"> <ul class="nav navbar-nav"> <li class="active"><a href="">Inicio</a></li> </ul> <!-- <ul class="nav navbar-nav"> <li><a href="#"></a></li> </ul> --> </div> </div> </nav> </header>

<div class="container">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-xs-12"> 

<button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-lg btn-block" value="Input Button" onclick="location.href = '/LED=ON';"> Encender</button>

<button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-lg btn-block" value="Input Button" onclick="location.href = '/LED=OFF';"> Apagar</button>
</div>
</div> </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Cuando llamas a esa url que deberia de retornarte? un true o un false? te pregunto porque cuando hacemos el ajax deberias de resivir una respuesta para ver si fue existoso o no

Answer (score 1):

El problema es que, por lo que veo en el código, tienes que navegar una página para poder avisar de que se tiene que encender o apagar la luz, por eso se recarga la página.

Tal vez lo que podés hacer es navegarla en un iframe oculto, para que se ejecute la página pero no se refresque.
Sería algo así:

```
<iframe name="aaa" style="position:absolute;top:-10px;width:1px;height:1px"></iframe>
<button onclick="window.open('/LED=ON', 'aaa');">Encender</button>
```

Espero te sirva.

¡Suerte!

Answer (score 0):

Existe una tecnología llamada AJAX la cual te permite realizar procesos asíncronos.  Puedes darte una vuelta por este link para que te leeas un poco más sobre AJAX

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_(programming)